# java user defined function in oracle using byte[]

Tags: java, sql, oracle, user-defined-functions, java-stored-procedures

Given this table in Oracle

```
create table test (bytes raw(100), chset varchar2(50))
insert into test (bytes, chset) values (hextoraw('454647'), 'iso-8859-1')
```

or in MSSQL

```
create table test (bytes varbinary(100), chset nvarchar(50))
insert into test (bytes, chset) values (0x454647, 'iso-8859-1')
```

I'm looking for a comprehensive example of how to create a UDF for Oracle in Java that makes use of Java's text encoding support.

In MSSQL I would create this .Net assembly:

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace Whatever
{
    public class Common
    {
        [SqlFunction]
        public static string Decode(byte[] Bytes, string EncodingName)
        {
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(EncodingName).GetString(Bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

and use these commands to register the assembly and define the udf:

```
create assembly MyAssembly from '...\MyAssembly.dll'

create function decode(@bytes varbinary(max), @chset nvarchar(100))
returns nvarchar(max) as external name MyAssembly.[Whatever.Common].Decode
```

and use it in a query like this:

```
> select *, dbo.decode(bytes, chset) decoded from test

bytes      chset       decoded
0x454647   iso-8859-1  EFG
```

---

## update

so far I've created this Java class:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Common
{
    public static String Decode(byte[] Bytes, String CharsetName)
    {
        return Charset.forName(CharsetName).decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(Bytes)).toString();
    }
}
```

and used these commands to create the UDF:

```
create directory jdir as 'C:\...';
create java class using bfile (jdir, 'Common.class');

create function jdecode(bytes raw, chset varchar2) return nvarchar2 as language java
name 'Common.Decode(java.lang.byte[], java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

but when I try to use it I get this error:

```
> select jdecode(hextoraw('454647'), 'iso-8859-1') from dual

ORA-29531: no method Decode in class Common
```

---

## update 2

turns out java.lang.byte[] isn't a thing, changing it to just byte[] got things working. Thanks Tim!

```
create function jdecode(bytes raw, chset varchar2) return nvarchar2 as language java
name 'Common.Decode(byte[], java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

there's a handy table here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chsix.htm#BABJIJEB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a user defined function (UDF) java or otherwise when oracle already provides sufficient utilities for such conversions?

The `UTL_I18N` package supplies all the needed functionality.  The `MAP_CHARSET` funtion maps from ISO character set names to Oracle character set names, then the `RAW_TO_CHAR` function converts your raw data of the specified character set to a `VARCHAR2` in the database character set.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe159/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test (bytes raw(100), chset varchar2(50));
insert into test (bytes, chset) values (hextoraw('454647'), 'iso-8859-1');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*
     , UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR( bytes
                           , UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(chset,0,1)) decoded
 from test t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe159/5/0)**:

```
| BYTES |      CHSET | DECODED |
|-------|------------|---------|
|  RUZH | iso-8859-1 |     EFG |
```

Comment: This was actually just a toy problem to try to understand how to get a java written UDF running in Oracle - it ended up being the silly mistake "byte vs. java.lang.byte" for which Oracle was not giving a very informative error message.